# Jumble numbers in an array such that no two adjacent numbers are same using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, grouping

The idea it to basically not have repeated values in the array with similar values.

An example input array:

```
input = [1,2,2,2,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

Expected output to be something like this:

```
desiredOutput = [1,2,3,2,4,2,5,2,6,2,7,8,9]
```

I have tried putting this in a for loop where it checks with the next item and if it is same, swaps the values. The problem is when I have continuous similar values.

Comment: Mention your codes , what did you tried so far ..

Comment: could the expected array also look like `[9,2,3,1,4,2,5,2,6,2,7,8,2]`

Comment: @RohitKumar this is what I tried so far
Looping the array, comparing the next item from the index value to the current one. If truthy, compare the current item to the next next item. if not truthy, switch. Else, keep going till I find a different value and switch.

Comment: you have accepted a answer , so undo that if that doesn't work and edit your question with codes you tried

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This proposal features

- count of elements and store it in an appropriate object,
- check whether spread is possible (e.g. not here `[1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3]`),
- round robin with the elements, so
- maximum distance between the same elements.

> How does it work?
>
> As example I take this array: `[1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`
>
> 1. Build an object with the count of the elements, store it with the element as key.
>
>    ```
>    length = {
>          "1": 1, "2": 4, "3": 1, "4": 1, "5": 1, "6": 1, "7": 1, "8": 1, "9": 1
>      }
>    ```
> 2. Select the property with the largest value: `length[2] = 4`
> 3. Make a new array with the length of the previous value and fill it with empty arrays.
>
>    ```
>    output = [[], [], [], [], []]
>    ```
> 4. Check if a spreaded array is possible. If not, return.
> 5. Set `k` to the key of the biggest value of a property.
>
>    ```
>    k = '2'
>    ```
> 6. If truthy, proceed. Otherwise go to 11.
> 7. Set `l` to the value of `length[k]`.
>
>    ```
>    l = 4
>    ```
> 8. Iterate over `l` and push `k` to the end of the array with the index of `i % outputLength`. Increase `i`.
> 9. Delete property `k`.
> 10. Proceed with 5.
> 11. Return the flat `output` array.
>
>     ```
>     output   first  then continued
>     array 0:     2     1     6
>     array 1:     2     3     7
>     array 2:     2     4     8
>     array 3:     2     5     9
>
>     return:      2  1  6  2  3  7  2  4  8  2  5  9
>     distance     |        |        |        |       is equal
>     ```

```js
function spread(input) {

    function findMaxKey() {
        var max = 0, key;
        Object.keys(length).forEach(function (k) {
            if (length[k] > max) {
                max = length[k];
                key = k;
            }
        });
        return key;
    }

    var length = input.reduce(function (r, a) {
            r[a] = (r[a] || 0) + 1;
            return r;
        }, {}),
        i = 0, k = findMaxKey(), l,
        outputLength = length[k],
        output = Array.apply(Array, { length: outputLength }).map(function () { return []; });

    if (input.length - outputLength < outputLength - 1 ) {
        return; // no spread possible
    }
    while (k = findMaxKey()) {
        l = length[k];
        while (l--) {
            output[i % outputLength].push(k);
            i++;
        }
        delete length[k];
    }
    return output.reduce(function (r, a) { return r.concat(a) }, []);
}
console.log(spread([1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]));
console.log(spread([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]));
console.log(spread([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]));
console.log(spread([1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3]));
console.log(spread([1, 1, 3]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm tinkering with this and will let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

maybe that could help you:

```
for(var i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
    if(input[i-1] == input[i]) {
        var j = i;
        while(j < input.length && input[j] == input[i]) {
            j++;
        }
        var el = input[j];
        input[j] = input[i];
        input[i] = el;  
    }
}
```

Comment: Tinkering with this as well.

Answer (score 0):

## Greedy Approach Using Max Heap

The idea is to greedily put the highest frequency numbers first.

1. Construct a max heap where every node is a tuple that stores the number & it's frequency.
2. Then extract the head of the max heap (the highest frequency node) and add it's value to the resultant array.
3. If there's a previous element then add it back to the heap.
4. Decrement the frequency of the extracted node and store it in `prev`, so that it can be added back after one iteration.
5. Finally return the solution if it exists otherwise return the string `"Not Possible"`.

```js
function solution(arr) {
  const maxHeap = Array.from(
    arr.reduce((m, i) => m.set(i, (m.get(i) ?? 0) + 1), new Map())
  ).sort(([, a], [, b]) => b - a);
  
  const res = [];
  let prev = null;
  
  while (maxHeap.length) {
    const maxNode = maxHeap.shift();
    res.push(maxNode[0]);
    maxNode[1] -= 1;
    if (prev) {
      maxHeap.push(prev);
      maxHeap.sort(([, a], [, b]) => b - a);
      prev = null;
    }
    if (maxNode[1] > 0) {
      prev = maxNode;
    }
  }
  return res.length < arr.length ? "Not Possible" : res;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(solution([1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(solution([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(solution([1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(solution([1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3])));
console.log(JSON.stringify(solution([1, 1, 3])));
```

*Note: I've not implemented a Max Heap (because it's tedious), I've simulated it with `Array.prototype.sort`.*