# Sorting array alternating data

Tags: javascript, sorting

Given an array, I need rearrange the the elements so that no two adjacent elements are the same. The ordering does not matter.

```
var list = ['a','c','c','a','b','b'];

//expected ['a','c','a','b','c','b'];

var listb = ['a','c','c','c','c','a'];

//expected ['a','c','a','c','c','c'];
```

The rule is: the next item never should be equal to the previous.

**UPDATE**

More rules:

- The first item never should be touched, keep it
- The rest of equals items should be at the end

Comment: The next item never should be equal than the previous, is that the rule ?

Comment: So, if the current element is the same as the previous one, you want to swap it for the next one?

Comment: You really haven't asked a clear question. What exactly is the sort rule you want followed?

Comment: Sorry, yes the next item never should be equal than the previous.

Comment: Do you need to sort or just alternate ? `The order alphabetic doesn't care` ???

Comment: just alternate, the order alphabetic doesn't care

Comment: This isn't sorting as far as I can tell from your question. You just need to iterate and check the adjacent elements for equivalence and move them if need be. You will need a special case to handle the final two elements and also keep in mind that there could be input where it is impossible to achieve what you want.

Comment: What's the expected result for a list such as `['a', 'a', 'b', 'a']`? And should the original order be somehow respected?

Comment: The original order should be respected.
The result should be ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a']

Comment: @Joel : What have you done till now?  Please post your code.

Comment: @JoelLovera: *How* should it be respected? And when exaclty should the rule be broken? What should happen to `['b', 'a', 'a', 'a']` (and why)?

Comment: maybe you have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667815/jumble-consecutive-same-items-in-an-array-such-that-the-output-array-has-no-cons/32669625#32669625, ther only the `// no spread possible` has to be deleted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution and works as expected

```
var alternate = function(list) {
    var index = 0;
    var list_size = list.length;
    var process = function(list_process) {

        // Search the next item different, remove and return this.
        var serchNextDifferent = function(number) {
            for (var i = index+1; i <= list_size; i++) {
                if (list_process[i] !== number) {
                    return list_process.splice(i,1)[0];
                }
            }
        };
        // Search the next item different, remove and return this.
        var serchPrevDifferent = function(number, index) {
            for (var i = index-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                if (list_process[i] !== number && list_process[i] !== list_process[index] && number !== list_process[i-1] && i) {
                    return list_process.splice(i,1)[0];
                }
            }
        };
        // Check if the current item and the prev are equals
        if (list_process[index-1] === list_process[index]) {
            var next = serchNextDifferent(list_process[index]);
            if (next) {
                list_process.splice(index, 0, next[0]);
            } else {
                var prev = serchPrevDifferent(list_process[index], index);
                if (prev) {
                    list_process.splice(index-1, 0, prev[0]);
                } else {
                    list_process.push(list_process.splice(index, 1)[0]);    
                }
            }
        }

        // next
        if (list_size-1 !== index) {
            index++;
            return process(list_process);
        } else {
            return list_process; 
        }
    };
    return process(list);
};
```

Here is the working example [Link](https://jsbin.com/zuwiguxeje/edit?js,console)

Comment: i have posted 20 hours ago something very similar ! have you see it ?

Comment: It seems to be wrong according your rule for `['a','c','c','c','c','a']`, the better result should be : `['c','a','c','c','a','c']` where you have only 2 contigous letter better than 3 : `['a','c','a','c','c','c']`. the rule : ***the next item never should be equal to the previous***

Comment: The better result for `['a','c','c','c','c','a']` is  ['a','c','a','c','c','c']`.
The rest of equals items should be at the final

Comment: `The rest of equals items should be at the final`, `but the first item doesn't should touch never` This are ***a rules*** and they ***must*** be in the question, not in the comments of answers

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an interesting question.

So if I am not mistaken, then these are the rules:

1. The next item never should be equal than the previous
2. The first item never should be touched, keep it
3. It should just alternate, the order alphabetic doesn't care
4. The rest of equals items should be at the end

I've taken a recursive approach.
Maybe this is what you are looking for?

> These are the results:
>
> ['a','c','c','a','b','b'] => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'c']
>
> ['a','c','c','c','c','a'] => ['a', 'c', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c']
>
> ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a'] => ['a', 'b', 'a', 'a']

```js
function alternateArray(originalArray) {
  var resultArray = [];
  var allValuesSame = function(myArray) {
    for (var p = 0; p< myArray.length; p++) {
      if (myArray[0] != myArray[p]) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  };
  var process = function (originalArray, resultArray) {
    if (originalArray.length == 0) {
      return resultArray;
    }
    // Find a suitable spot that would respect the alternating requirement
    for (var i = originalArray.length -1; i>=0; i--) {
      var replaced = false;
      for (var j = 1; j<resultArray.length-1; j++) {
        if (resultArray[j] && resultArray[j+1]) {
          if (resultArray[j] != originalArray[i] && resultArray[j+1] != originalArray[i]) {
            resultArray.splice(j+1, 0, originalArray.splice(i, 1)[0]);
            replaced = true;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      if (replaced) {
        continue;
      }
      // If no suitable spot was found, lets try the end of the resultArray
      if (resultArray[resultArray.length-1] != originalArray[i]) {
        resultArray.push(originalArray.splice(i, 1)[0]);
        continue;
      }
      if (allValuesSame(originalArray) && originalArray.length > 0) {
        // Rule: the rest of equals items should be at the end
        for (var z = 0; z < originalArray.length; z++) {
          resultArray.push(originalArray[i]);
        }
        return resultArray;
      }
    }

    return process(originalArray, resultArray)
  };
  // Rule: keep the first item (Rule)
  if (originalArray[0]) {
    resultArray.push(originalArray.splice(0, 1)[0]);
  }
  return process(originalArray, resultArray);
}

console.log(alternateArray(['a','c','c','a','b','b']));
console.log(alternateArray(['a','c','c','c','c','a']));
console.log(alternateArray(['a', 'a', 'b', 'a']));
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have modified Durstenfeld shuffle algorithm:

```
function shuffleArray(array) {
    for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        var j;
        var count = 0;
        do {
            j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            count++;
        } while(i!=array.length && array[i+1] == array[j] && count < 500);

        var temp = array[i];
        array[i] = array[j];
        array[j] = temp;
    }
    return array;
}
```

The only thing which can appear here is that first letter might be equal to second. But it's easy to check and fix.

Here is working example with above problem fixed: https://jsfiddle.net/1zeafb31/

```js
(function() {
    var list = ['a','c','c','a','b','b'];
    var sortedList = list.sort();

    var shuffleArray = function(array) {
        for (var i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            var j;
            var count = 0;
            do {
                j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
                count++;
            } while(i!=array.length && array[i+1] == array[j] && count < 500);

            var temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
        }
        if(array.length > 1 && array[0] == array[1]) {
            var temp = array[0];
            array[0] = array[array.length - 1];
            array[array.length-1] = temp;
        }
        return array;
    }
    
    document.getElementById('randomize').onclick = function(e) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = shuffleArray(list).join(' ');
    };
    
})();
```

```html
<div id='result'></div>

<br>
    <button id='randomize'>Randomize</button>
```

Comment: - don't should be random, should respect the origin orden
- if use this array ['b','b','b','b','a','c','c','a','b','b','b'] should return the sames 'b' at the final

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to build a list you use to count occurrences of each character in the input string, sort this occurrence list by character code and generate a new string having the same length as the input string by iterating the occurrence list.

```
function shuffle(src) {
  if ('string' != typeof src) {
    throw new Error('Invalid source string.');
  }

  if (src.length < 3) {
    return src;
  }

  var countersByChar = {};
  var countersList = [];

  // STEP 1: Count each character occurrence.
  for (var i = 0; i < src.length; ++i) {
    var chr = src[i];
    var counter = countersByChar[chr];

    if (!counter) {
      counter = {
        chr: chr,
        count: 0
      };

      countersByChar[chr] = counter;
      countersList.push(counter);
    }

    ++counter.count;
  }

  // STEP 2: Sort counters list by character code.
  countersList.sort(function(lhs, rhs) {
    return lhs.chr.charCodeAt(0) - rhs.chr.charCodeAt(0);
  });

  // STEP 3: Generate a new permutation.
  var charsLeft = src.length;
  var p = 0;
  var dest = [];

  while(charsLeft) {
    var c = countersList[p];
    dest.push(c.chr);

    if (!--c.count) {
      countersList.splice(p, 1);
    } else {
      ++p;
    }

    if (p == countersList.length) {
      p = 0;
    }

    --charsLeft;
  }

  var result = dest.join('');
  return result;
}

function test(src) {
  alert('shuffle("' + src + '") => ' + shuffle(src));
}

test('accabb');
test('acccca');
```

And here is the working example: https://jsfiddle.net/pbcq2o3y/

```js
    function shuffle(src) {
      if ('string' != typeof src) {
        throw new Error('Invalid source string.');
      }

      if (src.length < 3) {
        return src;
      }

      var countersByChar = {};
      var countersList = [];

      // STEP 1: Count each character occurrence.
      for (var i = 0; i < src.length; ++i) {
        var chr = src[i];
        var counter = countersByChar[chr];

        if (!counter) {
          counter = {
            chr: chr,
            count: 0
          };

          countersByChar[chr] = counter;
          countersList.push(counter);
        }

        ++counter.count;
      }

      // STEP 2: Sort counters list by character code.
      countersList.sort(function(lhs, rhs) {
        return lhs.chr.charCodeAt(0) - rhs.chr.charCodeAt(0);
      });

      // STEP 3: Generate a new permutation.
      var charsLeft = src.length;
      var p = 0;
      var dest = [];

      while(charsLeft) {
        var c = countersList[p];
        dest.push(c.chr);

        if (!--c.count) {
          countersList.splice(p, 1);
        } else {
          ++p;
        }

        if (p == countersList.length) {
          p = 0;
        }

        --charsLeft;
      }

      var result = dest.join('');
      return result;
    }

    function test(src) {
      alert('shuffle("' + src + '") => ' + shuffle(src));
    }

    test('accabb');
    test('acccca');
```

Comment: The input should be an array like ['a','b','a','b','a'] or ['hello','bye','hello','bye','hello']

Answer (score 0):

***edit*** :
*This answer does not take care of the two rules added to the question, after this answer was posted.*

---

This is a naïve answer, I don't know about performance, efficiency or optimisation, but this can do the job.

For one use case it is not matching, what you expected :

given array : `["a","c","c","c","c","a"]`
expected-> : `["a","c","a","c","c","c"]`
result - - - > :`["c","a","c","c","a","c"]`

I think the expected don't respect the **only** rule you provide :

> the next item ***never*** should be equal to the previous

But the result respect much more the rule !

---

*I hope this will help you.*

```js
/* debug purpose */
var el = document.getElementById('el');
var j = JSON.stringify;

var log = function(val) {
  console.log(val);
  el.innerHTML += '<div><pre>' + val + '</pre></div>'
};

var tmpl = function(argList, argResult, argExpected){
  log( j(argList)  + '\n\t become\n' + j(argResult) +
    "\n\texpected\n" + j(argExpected) + 
    " matching : " + 
    (j(argResult) === j(argExpected) ) 
  );

};

/* Main function */
var Alternate = function(listToAlternate) {

  var clone = listToAlternate.slice(0);

  var nextNot = function(val, from, arr) {
    var idx = from + 1;
    for ( idx; idx <= arr.length ; idx++ ) {
      if (arr[ idx ] != val && arr[ idx + 1 ] != val) return idx;
    }
    return from;
  };
  
  var prevNot = function(val, from, arr) {
    var idx = from - 1;
    for ( idx; idx >= 0; idx-- ) {
      if ( arr[ idx ] != val && arr[ idx - 1 ] != val) return idx;
    }
    return from;
  };  
 
  
  var len = clone.length;
  
  var prev = '';
  var curPos;
  var curVal;
  var repetition;
  
  for( var i = 0 ; i < len ; i++){
    
    curPos = i;
    curVal = clone[ curPos ];
    
    if(curVal == prev){
  
      repetition = clone.splice( curPos , 1)[0];// remove
      
      var nextPos; 
      if(curPos === len){
        nextPos = prevNot(repetition , curPos , clone);// lookFor
      } else {
        nextPos = nextNot(repetition , curPos , clone);// lookFor
      }
      
      clone.splice(nextPos , 0 , repetition); //insert
    }
  
    prev = clone[i];
  };

  prev = '';
  curVal = undefined;
  curPos = undefined;
  repetition = undefined;
  
  for( var i = len-1 ; i>=0  ; i--){
    curPos = i;
    curVal = clone[ curPos ]
    
    if(curVal == prev){
      
      repetition = clone.splice( curPos , 1)[0]; // remove
      var prevPos = prevNot(repetition , curPos , clone); // lookFor
      clone.splice(prevPos , 0 , repetition); // insert
      
    }
  
    prev = clone[i];
  };

  return clone;
};




/* Use case testing */
var list;
var expected;



list     = ['a','c','c','a','b','b'];
expected = ['a','c','a','b','c','b'];
result   = Alternate( list );

tmpl( list , result , expected);


list = ['a','b','b','a'];
expected = ["a","b","a","b"];
result   = Alternate( list );

tmpl( list , result , expected);


list = ['a','a','b','a'];
expected = ["a","b","a","a"];
result   = Alternate( list );

tmpl( list , result , expected);


list = ['a','c','c','c','c','a'];
expected = ['a','c','a','c','c','c'];
result   = Alternate( list );

tmpl( list , result , expected);


list = ['hello','hello', 'bye','bye','hello'];
expected = ['hello','bye','hello','bye','hello'];
result   = Alternate( list );

tmpl( list , result , expected);


list = ['b','b','b','b','a','c','c','a','b','b','b'];
result   = Alternate( list );

log( j( list ) + '\n\t become\n' + j( result ) );


list = ['a','c','c','c','a','b','b','z'];
result   = Alternate( list );

log( j( list ) + '\n\t become\n' + j( result ) );
```

```css
div{
  border : solid 1px #EEE;
  }
```

```html
<div id='el'></div>
```

Comment: Sorry, it works ok, but the first item doesn't should touch never, I know I forget add to the question description

Comment: @JoelLovera How can we provide an answer if in the question it miss the essential ? ;-) glad you found an answer !