# Ordering Array for best pie chart display (keep small values apart)

Tags: objective-c, arrays, algorithm, sorting

#### I'm going to be writing this algorithm in Objective-C, but the answer does not have to be written in that language.

I'm facing a problem where I have data arrays that are randomly generated (for now) or generated from real-life data, and I'm trying to display this data on a pie chart. The pie chart is grouping the data elements by type. The way the data comes in from a web service currently dictates the "order" of the elements around the donut's ring, meaning that there is no standard, default sort.

With a small number of elements, or with elements that are fairly evenly distributed, the display looks good.

E.g., if I have 100 data points that are generally evenly distributed among 5 categories (so, about 20 per category), the display is fine.

But it can happen that 2 of the categories have small values (say, 4% or so). Sometimes, when that happens, the small values can end up next to one another, which causes some display issues.

So, the general goal I'm trying to achieve is this:

- Given a data set as an array of objects with a numeric value property, re-order the array so that small values are as evenly-distributed as possible.

So, in Objective-C, it might be an `NSArray` of `NSDictionary` objects.

What comes in might look like this:

```
NSArray *colors = @[@{@"color": @"Red"   , @"number": @(45)},
                    @{@"color": @"Blue"  , @"number": @(4)},
                    @{@"color": @"Green" , @"number": @(4)},
                    @{@"color": @"Yellow", @"number": @(4)},
                    @{@"color": @"Orange", @"number": @(45)}];
```

After processing, the result should look something like this (actual order is less important than the relative value of adjacent `@"number"` values):

```
@[@{@"color": @"Blue"  , @"number": @(4)},
  @{@"color": @"Red"   , @"number": @(45)},
  @{@"color": @"Green" , @"number": @(4)},
  @{@"color": @"Orange", @"number": @(45)},
  @{@"color": @"Yellow", @"number": @(4)}];
```

Note that this is for display purposes only, so the placement of Red and Orange could switch and still be a valid output. Same with Blue, Green and Yellow.

So far, the best idea I've come up with is to originally sort the items using a traditional method, then construct a new array by pulling items from the sorted array, alternating by taking items from the beginning of the array and then the end of the array.

So, to use the first array given above, the traditional sort might produce this array:

```
@[@{@"color": @"Blue"  , @"number": @(4)},
  @{@"color": @"Green" , @"number": @(4)},
  @{@"color": @"Yellow", @"number": @(4)},
  @{@"color": @"Red"   , @"number": @(45)},
  @{@"color": @"Orange", @"number": @(45)}];
```

Then, I would construct the final outcome by alternating pulling an item from the beginning and then the end of that array (in this case, a 5-step process). So, here are the 2 arrays during the 5 steps:

```
Step 1

Interim Array
  @[@{@"color": @"Green" , @"number": @(4)},
    @{@"color": @"Yellow", @"number": @(4)},
    @{@"color": @"Red"   , @"number": @(45)},
    @{@"color": @"Orange", @"number": @(45)}];

Final Array
  @[@{@"color": @"Blue"  , @"number": @(4)}];
```

---

```
Step 2

Interim Array
  @[@{@"color": @"Green" , @"number": @(4)},
    @{@"color": @"Yellow", @"number": @(4)},
    @{@"color": @"Red"   , @"number": @(45)}];

Final Array
  @[@{@"color": @"Blue"  , @"number": @(4)},
    @{@"color": @"Orange", @"number": @(45)}];
```

---

```
Step 3

Interim Array
  @[@{@"color": @"Yellow", @"number": @(4)},
    @{@"color": @"Red"   , @"number": @(45)}];

Final Array
  @[@{@"color": @"Blue"  , @"number": @(4)},
    @{@"color": @"Orange", @"number": @(45)},
    @{@"color": @"Green" , @"number": @(4)}];
```

---

```
Step 4

Interim Array
  @[@{@"color": @"Yellow", @"number": @(4)}];

Final Array
  @[@{@"color": @"Blue"  , @"number": @(4)},
    @{@"color": @"Orange", @"number": @(45)},
    @{@"color": @"Green" , @"number": @(4)},
    @{@"color": @"Red"   , @"number": @(45)}];
```

---

```
Step 5

Interim Array
  @[];

Final Array
  @[@{@"color": @"Blue"  , @"number": @(4)},
    @{@"color": @"Orange", @"number": @(45)},
    @{@"color": @"Green" , @"number": @(4)},
    @{@"color": @"Red"   , @"number": @(45)},
    @{@"color": @"Yellow", @"number": @(4)}];
```

From what I can tell, this algorithm should give me the output that I need within reason. I realize that some display values will just be hard. For instance, if I get values of `[88,4,4,4]`, there's no way to separate the 4's from one another. That's OK. I'm trying to do something that is fairly straightforward to reasonably optimize real-world graph data.

So, some basic questions:

1. Is there an established sort algorithm for this type of use case?
2. If not, are there any major flaws in the algorithm I've developed? It will not be used to sort very large arrays (probably a maximum of 10-ish objects). I'm ok with "outlier" cases like the one I mentioned above. Again, I'm just trying to **reasonably** optimize the display.

If it matters to the solution, the charting library I'm using is Daniel Gindi's Charts for iOS.

Comment: I think you've got a good idea, proceed from the top of the list down, inserting from the bottom up.  I think @CRD is suggesting "middle-out", which is the best algorithm in Silicon Valley.

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32667815/1447675) helps.

Comment: @CRD Thanks for your idea. I actually did implement your idea, and it gave pretty similar results to my original idea. I think that's to do with the smaller data sets I'm processing. If you put it in an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Originally a comment)*

(1) Not that I know.
(2) No.

You might try weaving from the start and the middle (rather than end) so the largest and smallest don't end up adjacent and the middle ones don't end up adjacent - but really what you're doing sounds good.

Comment: Thanks! I did this and it seemed to work well. Looks like we figured out 2 viable solutions to this problem.