# merge array of arrays without repeating values from same array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, merge

I am looking for a javascript solution to get an array by merging multidimensional array without forming clusters of values from same arrays.

```
const collection = [['AA'], ['BBB'], ['CCCC']]
```

The result I would like to achieve is:

```
const result = ['ACBCABCBC']
```

The collection will always be sorted and it does not necessarily contain sub arrays with 1 element greater than previous element, it could be of any length larger than previous.

Comment: you may have alook here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32667815/jumble-consecutive-same-items-in-an-array-such-that-the-output-array-has-no-cons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
collections = [['AAAAAA'], ['BBB'], ['CCCC'], ['DDDDDDD'], ['EEEEEEEEEEE']];
collection = collections.map(e => { return String(e) });
function shuffle(collection) {

  collection.sort(function (a, b) {
    // ASC  -> a.length - b.length
    // DESC -> b.length - a.length
    return b.length - a.length;
  });
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 1; i < collection.length; i++) {
    sum += collection[i].length;
  }
  if (sum < collection[0].length) {
    return `Letters are bound to be repeated due to huge number of characters in one array`;
  }
  else {
    array = [];


    while (collection.length > 0) {
      let max = collection[0].length;
      for (let i = 1; i < max;) {
        if (collection.length == 1) {
if(collection[0][0])
          array.push(collection[0][0]);
          break;
        }
        else if (collection[i].length > 0) {
          array.push(collection[0][0]);
          array.push(collection[i][0]);
          temp1 = collection[0].split('');
          temp1.shift();
          collection[0] = temp1.join('');
          temp = collection[i].split('');
          temp.shift();
          collection[i] = temp.join('');
        }
        else {
          collection.splice(i, 1);
          collection.sort(function (a, b) {
            // ASC  -> a.length - b.length
            // DESC -> b.length - a.length
            return b.length - a.length;
          });
        }


      }
      collection.splice(0, 1);
      collection.sort(function (a, b) {
        // ASC  -> a.length - b.length
        // DESC -> b.length - a.length
        return b.length - a.length;
      });
    }


    array=array.join('');
    console.log('ANS:', array)
    return array
  }

}

shuffle(collection);
```

Check it and tell me if there's an edge case.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way, using `.map()`, `.reduce()`, `.join()` and `.split()` methods.

- First you transform each sub `array` into a `string`.
- Then you `reduce` all these `strings` into one `string`.
- Next you will need to transform back this `string` to an `array` of characters using `.split("")`.
- Finally you shuffle this `array` and transform it back to a `string`.

This is how should be your code:

```
var result = collection.map(e => e.join(""))
  .reduce((a, b) => (a + b))
  .split("");

result = shuffle(result);
result = [result.join("")];
```

**Demo:**

```js
function shuffle(a) {
  for (let i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [a[i], a[j]] = [a[j], a[i]];
  }
  return a;
}

const collection = [
  ['AA'],
  ['BBB'],
  ['CCCC']
]

var result = collection.map(e => e.join(""))
  .reduce((a, b) => (a + b))
  .split("");

result = shuffle(result);
result = [result.join("")];

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution but with random shuffling the order is unpredictable and I got this result back 'BCACCACBB' which has repeating values.

Comment: @shomail In that case we need to update the shuffle method.